# python splitting array into 2 arrays

Tags: python

I'm trying to separate the information within this array. It has the title, and the link

the first section is the title, and the last is the url.

```
 u'6 Essential Tips on How to Become a Full Stack Developer', 
 u'https://hackernoon.com/6-essential-tips-on-how-to-become-a-full- 
   stack-developer-1d10965aaead'

 u'6 Essential Tips on How to Become a Full Stack Developer', 
 u'https://hackernoon.com/6-essential-tips-on-how-to-become-a-full- 
   stack-developer-1d10965aaead'

 u'What is a Full-Stack Developer? - Codeup', 
 u'https://codeup.com/what-is-a-full-stack-developer/'

 u'A Guide to Becoming a Full-Stack Developer in 2017 \u2013 
   Coderbyte ...',  
 u'https://medium.com/coderbyte/a-guide-to- 
   becoming-a-full-stack-developer-in-2017-5c3c08a1600c'
```

I want to be able to push the titles in a list, as well as the links in a list. Instead of having everything in one list

here is my current code

**main.py**

```
from gsearch.googlesearch import search
from orderedset import OrderedSet
import re
import csv

results = search('Full Stack Developer')  # returns 10 or less 
          results

myAraay = list()

for x in results:
   owl = re.sub('[\(\)\{\}<>]', '', str(x))
   myAraay.append(owl)


newArray = "\n".join(map(str, myAraay))

print(newArray)
```

**Updated Main.py** (now getting cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects)

```
from gsearch.googlesearch import search
from orderedset import OrderedSet
import re
import csv

results = search('Full Stack Developer')  # returns 10 or less results

myAraay = list()

for x in results:
    owl = re.sub('[\(\)\{\}<>]', '', str(x))
    myAraay.append(owl)



newArray = "\n".join(map(str, myAraay))

theDict = {}                                     #keep a dictionary for title:link
for idx, i in enumerate(newArray):           #loop through list
    if idx % 2 == 0:                             #the title goes first...
        dict[i] = dict[i+1]                      #add title and link to dictionary
    else:                                        #link comes second
         continue                                #skip it, go to next title
print(theDict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the list is formatted such that the link always succeeds the title...

```
theDict = {}                                     #keep a dictionary for title:link
for idx, i in enumerate(OriginalList):           #loop through list
    if idx % 2 == 0:                             #the title goes first...
        dict[i] = dict[i+1]                      #add title and link to dictionary
    else:                                        #link comes second
         continue                                #skip it, go to next title
```

here it looks like

```
{"How to be Cool" : "http://www.cool.org/cool"}
```

If you want lists instead of dictionary its kind of the same...

```
articles = []                                    #keep a lists
for idx, i in enumerate(OriginalList):           #loop through list
    if idx % 2 == 0:                             #the title goes first...
        articles.append([i,i+1])                   #add title and link to list
    else:                                        #link comes second
         continue                                #skip it, go to next title
```

so here it looks like:

```
[["How to be Cool", "http://www.cool.org/cool"]]
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!